# TimedRotatingFileHandler: Log only when detected time to rotate

Tags: python

I have a function that makes calls to a logger almost every second, however, I only want to log information an hour before the logfile rotates.

Answer (score 1):

Use `logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename, when='H', interval=1)`